# Dropbox redirect

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I am accessing dropbox using:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<token>
```

I then log into dropbox and get the success page, but I am not redirected back to my site. Do I need to specify a callback URL, I thought dropbox would automatically redirect back?

Any ideas or thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Programming language? How are you making the `authorize` call?

Comment: Have to pass callbackURL with the authorizeURL.  I'd post the code but can't figure that out in a comment box.

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved:

```
https://www.dropbox.com/0/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=<token>&oauth_callback=http://www.google.com
```

> Need to pass the `callbackURL` along with the `authorizeURL`.